# byobu how to create a second column for multiple screens

Tags: 13.04, screen, byobu

So I have up to 12 different screens in byobu. However, after the 12 screen I can no longer fit it in my terminal session. I have a monitor 1024x780 so the 13th screen and there after are just display unless i continue to hit F4. Is there a way to wrap the screens into a second column?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to wrap the screens into a second column.

They do, however, exist, and you can use <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd> to scroll back and forth across all windows, beyond the 12 that fit on screen.

You could, perhaps, reduce the font size in your terminal, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd>, which would give you more real estate on screen.

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: Dustin thanks for your reply. I guess I can try to reduce the size of the terminal font. BTW thanks for contributing with your knowledge to Byobu. Its a great application!